# Montar imagenes con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estoy tratando de montar imagenes con php pero las voy a guardar en una carpeta y voy a guardar las rutas en phpmyadmin[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes el código ennimagen no es bien recibido, te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  para que pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Para los archivos (imágenes o documentos de cualquier tipo) se usa ```$_FILES[]```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action = "subir_imagen.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <!--PARA ADJUNTAR IMAGEN-->
 <h4>Seleccione imagen a cargar</h4>
     <label>Archivos</label>                         
     <input 
     type="file" 
     id="imagen[]" 
     name="imagen[]" 
     multiple="">                          
     <button  
      type="submit" 
      name="submit_img" 
      value="cambiar"
      >Cargar Imagen</button><p>  
</form> 
´´´´
subir_imagen.php

´´´´
//Llega hasta aqui por el boton de cargar imagenes... las almacena temporalmente, muestra una vista previa en el html
 
    var_dump($_FILES["imagen"]['name']);  // con esto podemos comprobar que traiga algun archivo
   
//Como el elemento es un arreglo que puede contener varios archivos utilizamos foreach para extraer todos los valores
    foreach($_FILES["imagen"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    { 
                $size = $_FILES["imagen"]["size"][$key];                            
                if($_FILES["imagen"]["size"][$key] >= 2097152) // 2MB
                {
                    $errores['size'][$key]= "El tamaño del archivo " .  $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$key] . " es superior al maximo permitido (2MB)";
                }
                else
                {
                    $filename = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre original del archivo
                    $source = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un nombre temporal del archivo
                    $mimetype = $_FILES["imagen"]['type'][$key]; 

                        if ($mimetype == "image/jpg" || $mimetype == "image/jpeg" || $mimetype == "image/png"|| $mimetype == "image/gif" )
                        {
                            $imagen_validada=true;
                            echo "imagen valida";
                            $directorio = 'uploads/images'; //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta donde guardaremos los archivos
                            //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la creamos
                                if(!file_exists($directorio))
                                {
                                mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");    
                                }           
                            $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
                            $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de destino, así como el nombre del archivo    
                            //Validamos que no exista un archivo con el mismo nombre en destino
                                if(is_file($target_path))
                                {   
                                   $errores['nombre'][$key]= "Ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre en la carpeta destino --> ".$filename; 
                                   @unlink(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
                                //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
                                    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) 
                                    {   
                                       $_SESSION['archivo'][$key] = $filename; //Guardo el nombre en una variable de sesion porque luego lo utilizo en el html
                                       $mensaje['imagen'][$key] = "El archivo " . $filename. " se ha subido en forma exitosa.";
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {   
                                        $errores['imagen'][$key]= "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.";
                                    }
                                }
                            closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $imagen_validada=false;
                            $errores['imagen'][$key]= "El archivo " . $filename . " debe ser de tipo JPG, JPEG, PNG o GIF.";
                            echo '<br>' . "esta imagen da un error" . '<br>';
                        }
                }    
        
    
  // Para guardar la imagen
$sqlImg ="INSERT INTO `imagen`  VALUES ($target_path');";

´´´´
```